# Changing text after it lands on the second photos on horizontal scrolling

Tags: figma

i'm new to figma and i wanted to build something where there are paragraph on the left side and a photos on the right side. so i used the horizontal scrolling with overflow scroll and i wanted to change the paragraph on the left side every time he user lands on a different photo available. how do i do that?

May this photo helps :
[image: Kinda looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not possible in Figma at the moment. You will have to attach the text to the scrolling container for it to appear while the user scrolls.

You cannot efficiently and without glitches create the interaction you described.

#### Though, I have a proposed solution.

It's not exactly what you're looking for but it works.

1. Create a frame (let's call it `frame 1`)
2. Add your paragraph to the left
3. Create another frame (let's call it `carousel`) within `frame 1`
4. Add your images in `carousel` and make sure `Clip content` is enabled on the frame
5. Add an arrow (shortcut: `Shift + L`) to the right of the image (to indicate the user to tap/click)
6. Duplicate `frame 1`
7. Move the all the images in your `carousel` to the left till the next image appears
8. Add an arrow `Shift + L` to the left of the image (to indicate the user to tap/click)
9. Go to the `Prototype` tab while you have `carousel` selected and on `Overflow scrolling` select `Horizontal scrolling`
10. Add an interaction `On click` to the right arrow to `Navigate to frame 2` and the left arrow to `Navigate to frame 1` with `Smart animate`
11. Go to `Step 6` to add another image.

[Carousel Figma Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEvq0.png)